# double elimination bracket algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, math

I'm trying to figure out how to best handle a double elimination bracket. When I did my single elimination I did it like so

```
double rounds = Math.Round(Math.Log(totalfighters, 2));
double bye = Math.Pow(2, rounds) - totalfighters;
```

I basically had to figure out how many rounds and how many byes are needed, and then coded up how I would distribute the matches. On my match model I have the following:

```
Match {
   int fighter1
   int fighter2
   int winner
}
```

I've been racking my brains as to how I can use the code above (if possible) to generate a double elimination bracket. My main issue with the double eimination is generating the Loser's bracket properly. Been trying to use the following format:

http://www.printyourbrackets.com/7teamdoubleelimination.html

But I'm stuck on generating the loser's bracket.

Any thoughts? Or should I just compeltely ignore my algorithm for the single elimnation?

Comment: Your single elimination algorithm seems to assume the number of participants is a power of two. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Alternatively, I think your code has a bug for numbers of fighters slightly greater than a power of two.

Comment: Well, to be honest I forgot where I got the formula but my main concern on those two lines was to see how many byes I need after I get the number of rounds. I have several more lines that figures out how many matches are needed after figuring out the number of byes. I know that this is one of the sources where I based it off of http://www.indiana.edu/~r324/r324singleelimintro.htm

Comment: I think it could be fixed by using ceiling instead of round - the problem is that rounding log2(17) gets 4 rounds, and -1 byes.

Comment: Hmm. never thought of that, I might change it when I find the time, since, right now it's working fine for single elimination for up to 256. I'm more concerned with double elimination which I'm not sure that the formula will do the job. It can for generating the winners bracket, but not sure about the losers bracket.

Comment: What would happen if, starting with e.g. an 8-round bracket, you drew a 7-round bracket on top of that to handle the 128 first-round losers, a 6-round bracket for the 64 first-time losers from the second-round, etc.?  You'd end up with the best first-round loser, second-round loser, etc. (7 people), so put them in a 3-round bracket, whose winner plays the champion.  If the champion loses that, let the champion have one rematch.

Comment: How do you figure out the bye tho? http://www.printyourbrackets.com/7teamdoubleelimination.html

Answer (score 1):

In the more complicated double elimination case, it may be easier to just calculate the brackets, round by round, and let the number of rounds fall out as a result. Use data structures that can extend as you add rounds.

The exact rules matter. For example, presumably a fighter in the winners bracket bye carries on into the next round in the winners bracket, and no corresponding fighter is added to the losers bracket.